# Combine several jQuery filters into a single one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using 4 jQuery codes to filter some html elemets

jQuery codes are:

Price Filter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#price-range").slider({
         range: true,
         min: 0,
         max: 3000,
         values: [1, 2000],
         slide: function(event, ui) {
             $(".min-price-label").html("€" + ui.values[0]);
             $(".max-price-label").html("€" + ui.values[1]);

             $('article[data-price]').each(function() {
                 var dPrice = $(this).attr('data-price');
                 if (dPrice < ui.values[0] || dPrice > ui.values[1])
                     $(this).hide();
                 else
                     $(this).show();
             });
         }
     });
     $(".min-price-label").html("€" + $("#price-range").slider("values", 0));
     $(".max-price-label").html("€" + $("#price-range").slider("values", 1));
 });
```

Star Rating Filter:

```
var grabVal = "";
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        grabVal = $(this).val();
        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("article[data-stars='" + grabVal + "']").hide();
        } else {
            $("article[data-stars='" + grabVal + "']").show();
        }
    });

    if (!$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
        $("article").show();
    }
});
```

A Load more code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#hotel-list article:gt(4)').hide();
  $('#loadMore').click(function () {
  $('#hotel-list article:hidden:lt(2)').show();
      });
    });
  $('.myClass').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('src') == ""){
          $(this).closest('article').hide();
       }
    });
```

And finaly a code to hide all the articles that has an empty src""

```
$('.myClass').each(function(){
       if($(this).attr('src') == ""){
          $(this).closest('article').hide();
       }
    });
```

Html elements are as:

```
<article data-stars="<?php echo $StarRating[1];?>" data-price="<?php $Price[1];?>"> 
<figure>
<a href=""><img width="270" height="160" class="myClass" alt="" src="<?php echo $img[1];?>"></a>
</figure>
<div><p>Content ...</p></div
</article>
```

Tha codes are working but the script are canceling each other. I am trying to combine all of them to start filtering the html content properly and hope to get some help out here.

Comment: What do you mean combine filters? Most of the selectors in the script don't even exist in the html shown. If you want help with collisions please provide a demo that fully replicates the problem(s)

Comment: can you provide html and a demo of the working code and the specific functionality that you want to happen in the "super script" you're desiring

Comment: you may check the url: [link](http://bookingassist.ro/live/hotel-list.php?DesinationId=ICPB&RoomsNO=1&City=Istanbul&In=2015-01-26&Out=2015-01-27&Adults=1&Childs=0) is the testing site

Comment: @RazvanBaba there is nothing we can do to work with your remote site. Also, links rot over time. Create a simplified demo in jsfiddle.net or other live code sharing site. Not to mention that with a full page we have no idea what interacts with what or where the code even is without digging through numerous files